# C# How to Insert Multiple Row from one Column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to insert multiple rows from one column.

For my POS system like this.

| ID | Item Code | Total Qty | Qty of Pallets | Quantity Of A PalleT/Per Box | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Item 1 | 384 | 4 | 96 | 12/07/2014 |

After that I want to see this in my table for each pallet

| ID | Item Code | Qty in Box | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Item 1 | 96 | 12/07/2014 |
| 00001 | Item 1 | 96 | 12/07/2014 |
| 00001 | Item 1 | 96 | 12/07/2014 |
| 00001 | Item 1 | 96 | 12/07/2014 |

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried already

Comment: Some people might be able to infer the logic you are trying to apply here, others might jump to wrong conclusions. Could you please use some sentences or formulas to describe your problem in detail and then add the code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What happens if the `Total Qty` isn't exactly divisible by `Qty of Pallets`?

Comment: Total Qty is in Boxes, Qty of Pallets->4 and Qty of a Pallet-> 96, So i want to display 4 rows of each pallet where has 96 box

Comment: So if you had a value of `386` for `Total Qty` and `96` for `Quantity Of A PalleT/Per Box` would you still have 4 rows with `96`? What about if it were `382`?

Comment: I just want 4 rows with 96 box, so to display item 1 in 4 rows with 96 quantity/box

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more clarification

But overall, you need to use an `INSERT INTO SELECT` command

you can find more about it by searching, but here's a quick code for your case

Repeat the `SELECT` statement as many times you want the row's data copied in the second table :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
 ID,
 ItemCode,
 QtyInBox,
 Date 
)
(
 SELECT ID, ItemCode, QtyInBox, Date FROM table2 WHERE ID = 0001
 SELECT ID, ItemCode, QtyInBox, Date FROM table2 WHERE ID = 0001
 SELECT ID, ItemCode, QtyInBox, Date FROM table2 WHERE ID = 0001
 SELECT ID, ItemCode, QtyInBox, Date FROM table2 WHERE ID = 0001
)
```

This is the answer to your question according to the title, you just need to factor in the **Pallet** thing, and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a recursive CTE as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT ID, ItemCode, QuantityOfPalleTPerBox as  [Qty in Box], [Date],
           1 AS cn, QtyOfPallets
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID, ItemCode, [Qty in Box], [Date],
           cn+1, QtyOfPallets
    FROM CTE WHERE cn+1<=QtyOfPallets
  )
SELECT ID, ItemCode, [Qty in Box], [Date] FROM CTE
ORDER BY ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/w3piLX1V).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
INSERT INTO [table2] ([ID], [Item_Code], [Qty_in_Box], [Date])
        
  (
     SELECT [ID], [Item_Code], [Quantity_Of_A_PalleT/Per_Box], [Date] FROM [table1]  
    UNION ALL
     SELECT [ID], [Item_Code], [Quantity_Of_A_PalleT/Per_Box], [Date] FROM [table1]  
    UNION ALL
     SELECT [ID], [Item_Code], [Quantity_Of_A_PalleT/Per_Box], [Date] FROM [table1]  
    UNION ALL
     SELECT [ID], [Item_Code], [Quantity_Of_A_PalleT/Per_Box], [Date] FROM [table1] 

    )
```